# как сделать так чтобы при нажатие кнопки запускался таймер который периодически меняет рисунок

Tags: javascript

мне нужно чтобы эти рисунки загружались с локального диска.Как ето можна зделать?

Comment: "что скушать утром?" - такой же общий вопрос, ответ на который навряд вас удовлетворит

Comment: укажите больше данных

Comment: какие именно данные нужно указать?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myImg = document.querySelector('.myImg')

let i = 0

setInterval(() => {
  if(i == 4){
    i = 0
  }
  i++
  myImg.setAttribute('src',`./img/img${i}.jpg`)
  myImg.setAttribute('alt',`img${i}`)
},2000)

//в таком примере должна быть папка img где лижат картинки с именами img1,img2,img3,img4
```

```html
<img class="myImg" src="./img/img1.jpg" alt="img1">
```

но все это лишено смысла поскольку данные должны прийти через запрос из бекенда то есть с файловой системой должен взаимодействовать бекенд и отдавать фронту